# Multiple Results from Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I thought I'd risk a second question on here since the first one was answered so brilliantly!

Sorry for long post!

In a nutshell, I am creating a quiz which has 10 Questions - Multiple Choice A B C D - Then Multiple Answers - So Question One answer could be A B D.

I originally set this up with $_POST and got it to work, but decided I really wanted to learn how to put the results into a db.

I've managed to insert the results into fields for example:

```
    --------------------
    Question1 | A, B, C
    Question2 | A, C, D
    --------------------
```

So, I moved onto retrieving the results - to which I have got to work but I want to learn how I can improve it.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `Username` = '$testing'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
    $questionone[] = $row['question1'];        
    }          

    foreach ($questionone as $v) {
    }

    $mycount = 0;
    $questiononereturn = array($v);
    if(empty($questiononereturn))
    {
    echo("Missed. <br/><br/>");
    }
    else
    {
    $N = count($questiononereturn);
    echo "<div><strong>Question 1:</strong> You selected $N answers: ";
    for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
    echo($questiononereturn[$i] . " ");
    }
    }
    sort($questiononereturn);
    if($questiononereturn == array('A,B'))
    {
    echo '<br/> <b>Correct answer!</b> <br/></div>';
    $mycount++;
    }
```

I have tried to google for advice and been through quite a lot of Stackoverflow questions / answers - but I am not sure what term I need to be searching for.

So, my question is:

I need to retrieve another 9 results, what can I do to improve on what I have done? are there any flaws to what I have done? - I just want to learn.

(I know its not PDO - and I want to move onto that soon)

Thanks

Andy

Comment: you should start using mysqli now, mysql way of doing things is depriciated

Comment: @NewBee He's already said he'll be moving onto PDO soon.

Comment: @Andy By 'another 9 results' do you mean another 9 users, or another 9 questions for each user?

Comment: @Jamie talking about syntex and general approach, mysql and mysqli has not so big difference, both can be done in non procedural way too, thats why I aksed him to try and learn mysqli

Comment: @Jamie Sorry, another 9 questions for each user! - NewBee - Honestly, after I get this out of the way, I will jump straight onto what I should be doing!